# Cocoapods spec for external lib at http (shared location)

Tags: ios, cocoapods

As per http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source

There are different type of source type you can provide to download your depended library. Last one mentioned in that page is downloading from HTTP.

> Using HTTP to download a compressed file of the code. It supports zip,
>   tgz, bz2, txz and tar.
>
> spec.source = { :http =>
>   "http://dev.wechatapp.com/download/sdk/WeChat_SDK_iOS_en.zip" }

*My question:*

What if i want to download lib from http e.g.  myLib.a from http://mylocation.com/sharedlib/myLib.a.

Above help didn't support *.a and *.framework.

How to achieve it? What would be pod spec for me in this case.

> Question updated (31st-Jan-2014)

I got answers on how to configure for http download. Thanks James for help.

**One more question**
Where to configure username/passoword if it is required to access *.zip at http source.  As per my knowledge, cocoapods is using SSHkey funda instead of credential based authentication.

Is there any configuration in pod spec for credential entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When downloading your Pod code over HTTP, you'll likely want to provide it as a .zip file so that it can contain both your library (`myLib.a`) and any required header files. You could also provide these as part of a Git repository.

The best way to solve your problem is probably to take a look at some existing Podspecs that include the same sort of files that you're trying to include.

- The [Estimote SDK](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/EstimoteSDK/1.2.0/EstimoteSDK.podspec) includes a `.a` library file and headers. The library is identified by the `vendored_libraries` property, and the headers are under `source_files`. The Podspec also updates the `xcconfig` so that the `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` and `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` point to the required files.
- The [Reveal SDK](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Reveal-iOS-SDK/1.0.3/Reveal-iOS-SDK.podspec) is downloaded over HTTP as a `.zip` file, and includes a `.framework` file, which is identified by the `vendored_frameworks` property. It also updates `xcconfig` to set the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting to point to the correct location.

I hope by looking at these two examples, you can determine what you need for your own Podspec!

Comment: Thanks James. Still have some query. So i have to upload my lib and headers at my http location in zip format. Link of that location will go into  "s.source " entry of pod spec. Lets say i have created my podspec file which has all required info. What to do now?  What entry will go into podfile.

Comment: If you have your podspec file somewhere local (or uploaded to a server), you can specify it with the `:podspec` option: `pod 'MyPodName', :podspec => 'URL or path to podspec file'`

Comment: Thanks for help...Its working now. Estimote SDK example help me lot.

Comment: #james, Any idea how cocoapods will connect with private github repos. Cause currently i am using public repos just to verify cocoapods with my project. I want to keep it private so no one can use my pod specs.

Comment: @harshit2811 That's an old comment, but I found your comment while on doing some research. For the question on your comment, if someones else fall here, here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository/43892558#43892558