# Cocoapods with private git repository

Tags: github, cocoapods

I want to add to podfile private git repository, for example:

```
pod 'MyLibrary', :git => 'git@github.com:perfect/top-library.git', :branch => 'data/myLab'
```

But when I run "pod install" command I receive error:

```
[!] Error installing MyLibrary
[!] Failed to download 'MyLibrary'.
```

And the question is how to provide my credentials from git to cocoapods ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use SSH and have generated a SSH Key (more info [here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/))

```
$>more ~/.ssh/config
```

It should give you something like that:

```
Host SomeHostNameAlias
    HostName github.com
    User YourUserName
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile /Users/YourLocalAccount/.ssh/TheSSHKeyGenerated
```

Then, in your Podfile, you should be able to do something similar to this (I didn't put `:branch =>`, but if you need it, and also note that I replace then the `:` with a `/` in the path after the host replacement.):

```
pod 'MyLibrary', :git => 'ssh://git@SomeHostNameAlias/perfect/top-library.git'
```

Side note: I use this kind of behavior with Bitbucket. I'm not a big expert on SSH and GitHub, and there may be some little changes on the git path for instance.

Using the `Host` alias like this may also help you manage different SSH keys for the same HostName (like different account/SSH on the same Git Server), could be useful on SourceTree if you manage different clients, personal/work access, etc.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in missing ssh keys.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using SSH keys? You can give credentials using

```
https://username:password@github.com/username/top-library.git
```

But this is rather insecure.

Comment: I can't use http :(, because it is insecure.

Comment: Then try with SSH keys