# Pod install fails for private pod being served as binary from private repo

Tags: github, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I have a private pod and a private spec repo.  I am serving the pod as a binary, i.e. the podspec says:

```
s.source = { 
  :http => 'https://github.com/COMPANY/PROJECT/releases/download/v1.0/PrivatePod.zip' 
}
```

My Podfile has the following source information:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/COMPANY/Specs.git'
```

When I run `pod install` git prompts for a password to clone my private spec repo, which is great.

However, `pod install` tries to get the binary zip package using `curl` with no authentication, so GitHub returns 404:

```
Installing PROJECT 1.0 (was 1.0)

[!] Error installing PROJECT [!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/_g/52mwshws60v8622n81hv7h7w0000gn/T/d20170608-80045-1l3flqz/file.zip https://github.com/COMPANY/PROJECT/releases/download/v1.1/PrivatePod.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional
...
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

I don't want to make the binary public.  Is there a way I can tell CocoaPods to do some auth here?

I tried putting credentials in `.netrc`, which CocoaPods seems happy to use, but GitHub still fails the request with 404, even though I see curl is now using basic auth.  If I make API requests with curl using netrc for auth, I get responses just fine.  But I can't download the release asset.

I can get the release asset from the api endpoint using .netrc, but only if I specify `-H 'Accept: application/octet-stream'`, which I don't see how I can make CocoaPods do that.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository/43892558#43892558 ?

Comment: I did see that work-around.  The problem there is you have to commit the release binaries, instead of using Github's non-SCM hosting of bits.

Comment: GitHub support is saying they just don't support auth for release downloads.  They added it to some internal feature request list which will probably be ignored forever.  Oh well.  Answer: NOT POSSIBLE.  Host that crap somewhere else.

Comment: Do you need it just for yourself/small group of users? One approach that seems to work is to "fake" curl - write a shell script that, given the curl arguments, "does the right thing", and then replace the real curl by putting a symlink to your fake curl earlier in the path (such as /usr/local/bin). Of course, this doesn't scale well since every user of the library would have to do the same hack. There is also https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-downloader but I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: My goal is binary distribution for third parties.  The solution is to just not host the binary packages on github, since they don't support auth for non-api calls, as confirmed by their support people.

Comment: Running into the same issue here... Maybe we can fix this by sending a PR to CocoaPods to include the missing header? What do you think?

Comment: You could try.  I no longer work at the company that needed this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub just doesn't support this.  Solution: don't host the binary on github if the repo hosting it is private.

> GitHub support is saying they just don't support auth for release downloads. They added it to some internal feature request list