# Getting the latest code of a CocoaPods dependency that points to a branch

Tags: git, version-control, module, dependencies, cocoapods

This question is about how to get the latest code for CocoaPods-managed dependencies during development, i.e. without doing the whole "push a new podspec" dance.

#### Setup

Say we have three projects `A`, `B`, and `C`. The dependencies are such that `A` depends on `B`, and `B` depends on `C`. Each project resides in its own Git repository.

We figured we'd use a dummy minor version to identify the current state of the code. The podspecs reside in our own repository.

```
# A/Podfile
...
pod 'B', '1.dev'

# B/Podfile
...
pod 'C', '1.dev'

# B/B.podspec
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = 'B'
    s.version = '1.dev'
    ...
    s.dependency = 'C', '1.dev'
end

# C/C.podspec
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = 'C'
    s.version = '1.dev'
    ...
end
```

#### The Problem

We push a new commit to (the master branch of) `C`. We expect

```
A$ pod update
```

to retrieve the change. This does not happen.

#### Approaches

1. Whenever we (know to) want to pull the dependencies anew, do:

   ```
   A$ rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock
   A$ pod cache clean --all
   A$ pod install
   ```

   This definitely gets the latest code. However, it's a sledgehammer that's neither convenient nor efficient to do after every pull in `A`,  push in either `B` or `C`, or switching between branches in `A`.
2. In order to stick close to the setup, we'd have to create a whole new set of podspecs and Podfiles after every (meaningful) set of commits on a master branch (i.e. a merge of a feature branch), all with a new version `1.x-y` (`y` a build number or something); push the podspecs; and run `pod update` in `A` and `B`.

   While this may be feasible in a CI setup (which we unfortunately don't have, yet), it's prohibitive work to do manually. Git hooks may be a workaround.
3. On non-version branches, do

   ```
   # A/Podfile
   ... 
   pod 'A', :git => "...", :branch => "master"
   ```

   That is, circumvent the podspec repo. Unfortunately, this won't work here becaus `pod` will inspect `B.podspec` and find its dependency `C`, which we can not specify in a similar way. Also, `pod update` always re-installs, no matter if there were new commits.

#### Question

Is there a good (low maintenance) way to track branches with CocoaPods? If not, what are alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use local pods.

Architecture for sample:

```
SomeWhere/BigFolder
          -- ProjectAWithItsPodSpecFiles
          -- ProjectBWithItsPodSpecFiles
          -- ProjectCWithItsPodSpecFiles
```

This way in your PodFile A, you do:

```
pod 'MyCustomPodB', :path => '../FolderPodB'
pod 'MyCustomPodC', :path => '../FolderPodC'
```

This add the possibility to modify yourself the classes of your pod without asking for a `pod update`/git pull and also not prompting the *“MyFileInMyPod” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?* from XCode each time.

How do we tell everyone to do so, meaning keeping the architecture of folders?

Using [Repo](https://source.android.com/setup/using-repo), tool by Google!

What is this tool in a few lines:
It can pull from various git repositories at the same times keeping a synchronized work. 
You have a `manifest.xml` files where you specify the repositories, the branches, and the local path (for the local architecture). Here is a [tutorial](https://harrow.io/blog/using-repo-to-manage-complex-software-projects/).
If you are using private repositories, I'd suggest using an [HostAlias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository) with SSH Keys.

My coworker continues to use *Repo*, I don't really. I keep pulling/pushing each one of them one by one using *SourceTree.app*, I used *Repo* only for the "starter" and that created me my whole local architecture.

In our own project:

```
Projects/MainApp
Projects/CoreClasses
Projects/Custo, Like Colors, etc.
Projects/OtherModule
```

I, most of the time, work on *MainApp*, and need to modify *CoreClasses* without any issue this way.

Sample of our Manifest.xml (in another private repository where there is almost only file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
    <remote name="remoteName" fetch="ssh://git@ourCommonAlias/RestOfTheGitPathExceptTheLastComponent"/>
    <default revision="masterBranchIsToSetByDefaultIfNeeded"
           remote="bitbucket"
           sync-j="4" />
    <project name="MainApp.git" remote="remoteName" path="BigFolder/MainApp"/> <!-- The name is the last component of the repository, the path the local path, the remote, the "start of the ssh give previously -->
    <project name="CoreClasses.git" remote="remoteName" path="BigFolder/CoreClasses"/>
    <project name="Custo.git" remote="remoteName" path="BigFolder/Custo" revision="someBranchIfNeededThere"/>
    <project name="OtherModule.git" remote="remoteName" path="BigFolder/OtherModule"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: While one could use Git submodules to similar effect (I guess), using repo seems much less fickle. Thanks!