# How to use development pods across our team?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

When I set path for my development pod, I cant commit podfile - it will break `pod install` for other devs. So I keep podfile in another change list and its really annoying. Is there a better way to develop pod?
I found this: [link](https://medium.com/@euginedubinin/development-pods-de631774751e), it suggest to change to path every time I want to update something in my pod. But it's even worth than uncommited podfile.

Comment: You could use Repo (see there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476153/getting-the-latest-code-of-a-cocoapods-dependency-that-points-to-a-branch/47477379#47477379) or do it manually. In other words, each dev has to have the same folder hierarchy for the different projects/pods, so you can use relative paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *relative paths* for development pods.

You can ask your co-developers to always use the same folder hierarchy between your current project (with the *podfile*) and the others developments projects/pods (with the *podspec*).

You can also use *Repo* to automatically do it for you (could be useful when a new guy comes, and/or if you have plenty of different development pods). It will install different projects/(development)pods according to the hierarchy set in its manifest. You can check [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476153/getting-the-latest-code-of-a-cocoapods-dependency-that-points-to-a-branch/47477379#47477379) if needed.