# Trying to clone via SSH uses the wrong public key

Tags: git, macos, ssh, bitbucket

I created a new pair of ssh keys specifically for using bitbucket, they are sitting in my `~/.ssh` folder like this:

`config`         `id_rsa.pub`     `id_rsa_alt.pub`      `id_rsa`         `id_rsa_alt`

I want to use the rsa_alt keypair for bitbucket.

Firstly, I added the contents of `id_rsa_alt.pub` to my bitbucket account.

I realised that when I try to connect to my bitbucket account via SSH it won't know  whether to use my original keypair of the alternative keypair. So I added the following to my `config` file inside `~/ .ssh`.

```
# bitbucket account
Host bitbucket.org-BitBucketUsername
    HostName bitbucket.org
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_alt
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I also changed my git name on my mac like this:

```
git config --global user.name "BitBucketUsername"
```

However, when I try to clone my repo like this: `git clone git@bitbucket.org:myteam/myproject.git`

it asks for the passphrase for `id_rsa` rather than `id_rsa_alt`, like this:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your ssh configuration affects hosts named `bitbucket.org-BitBucketUsername`, but it's not clear this is the hostname you've used when setting up the remote in your local git repository. Can you update your question with the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: Hi, output is: origin https://BitBucketUsername@bitbucket.org/myteam/myproject.git

Comment: Use the `host` in the URL. cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository/43892558#43892558

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use what you have configured in `~/.ssh/config`, you need to use the SSH URL:

```
bitbucket.org-BitBucketUsername:myteam/myproject.git
```

That will use the `~/.ssh/id_rsa_alt` private key.

So:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/repository
git remote set-url origin bitbucket.org-BitBucketUsername:myteam/myproject.git
```