# How to specify a username for a private pod

Tags: cocoapods

I am setting up a private pod that will be used across our team. In my podfile I have something like:

```
pod 'MySDK', :git => 'https://myusername@bitbucket/...git'
```

Is there a way to replace myusername with the username that downloaded the current project.
I can get the current username by parsing the url from

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Plan B is to make a script that modifies the podfile before running pod install. I am curious if I can make it without this extra step?

Comment: I'd suggest to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository/43892558#43892558 and use for all of your team the same alias, like "MyTeamAliasToPrivateTeamRepo", or something like that, getting a same for all the team with all their own custom credential/access per user.

Comment: @Larme, thank you for the suggestion - I don't have ssh and generated keys, the workaround with script looks simpler to me

Comment: But then, you're editing the podfile, no? So you won't commit it? Because it will always be different, so you'll end up commit a "personal one".

Comment: Yes, this is the drawback - so what I am asking is is there some way to execute script from the syntax of podfile directly like - pod 'MySDK', :git => 'https://[#gemyuser]@bitbucket/...git'. I could also modify the local podspec ...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up, below is part of my podfile

```
  #try to keep the current git user in the pod url
  remoteUrl = %x|git config --get remote.origin.url|
  username = remoteUrl.scan(/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i).first
  podUrl = "https://#{username}/mycompany/myrepo.git"
  puts podUrl
  pod 'MySDK', :git => podUrl, :commit => 'commitid'
```

Works great for me! Respect to all cocopods devs that made it so customizable!

Comment: You are genius!