# Private pod not installing on other machine

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoapods, podspec

hope you are doing good, I have currently created a framework and that framework will be provided to others as a pod. I have successfully created a pod and installed it on my local machine[image]. When I share with other developers they are not able to install the pod, It is showing an error.[image]. My podfile is [image] . I have successfully added the ssh key as well to the github. Can someone please help me to fix this issue? I want others can install the pod file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error suggests that their public key file is in an incorrect format.

Comment: Yes, I have tried generating the new key and pod installed again still showing the same error. Can you please provide me an example of this?

Comment: Can they clone the git repo for your private pod? First make sure they can clone it like any repo, and then it will be possible for cocoapods to use it.

Comment: From what I understand, the git repo on GitHub is private and need a SSH Key. Check if cloning is possible with the URL you are using. Could it be that on that machine there are multiple SSH Keys to GitHub for different accounts? If yes, you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository/43892558#43892558 Or are even the account on the machine allowed to get your private repo?

Comment: @Yonat, They are not able to clone the repo, It is showing an error that load pubkey is an invalid format in their root folder where they don't have my id_rsa key. In this case how can we get the reference of the key? My pub key is SHA256:aH6Zf+v3uYg2XWU7U2XJ/V6eILASIiAPbdo3Mrr434Mk

Comment: @Larme, When I use the ssh URL on my machine, It is showing an error that Repo not found. I have followed the GitHub documentation for creating the SSH key. Can you please give me an example or something to configure this correctly?

Comment: pod 'IDPal' : you should use a `ssh://` maybe not only `git@github...`...

Comment: I think, it should be `:git => ssh://git@github.com:ALIAS/IDPal-Specs.git`, where ALIAS is set in your SSH Config (see previous linked question).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well, It is not working @Larme

Comment: Sorry, it seems it should be `:git => ssh://git@HostAlias:whatHiddenInRed/IDPal-Specs.git` See https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/80a89405ab9023894df7

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Larme. I have tried pod 'IDPal', :git => 'ssh://git@github.com:Arunperfutil/IDPal.git' but still I am facing an issue that,  
Error installing IDPal
 Failed to download 'IDPal': [!] /usr/bin/git clone ssh://git@github.com:Arunperfutil/IDPal.git /var/folders/15/00j5ccs130l753fjpg4zvg780000gn/T/d20210921-2328-13vpklv --template= --single-branch --depth 1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:Arunperfutil: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights

Comment: Is `github.com` what's written in your file in `~/.ssh/config` in the line `Host` for the corresponding SSH Key to GitHub? What's the content of `~/.ssh/config` (hide some value if needed with "***")

Comment: did I miss anything @Larme. I am stuck for the past 2 days but no luck. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: config file contains 
Host *
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   IdentitiesOnly yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237326/discussion-between-larme-and-arun).

Comment: You need to grant them access to the repo: From you repo GitHub page go to Settings > Manage access > Invite a collaborator.

Comment: @Yonat I have done that as well but no luck.

Comment: Can they browse to your repo on the GitHub site?

Comment: Yes, they can. One thing I wanna confirm here is the SSH key should be generated on their side and that key should be added to their GitHub account as well right @Yonat

Comment: Right. Another option is to use a personal access token as described here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token