# How to use multiple private specs repos on cocoapods?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podfile

I have two private specs repos on BitBucket, using different accounts. To access them, I created two SSH keys, tested and it's working. I can clone repos from both accounts.

As a side note, I have to use my username in one of the accounts. If I just use the git username, I always end up on the same account.

So, my podfile is something like that:

```
source 'git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx-specs.git'

pod 'Check', '0.2.1', :source => 'username@bitbucket.org:yyy/yyy-specs.git'
```

when I run the pod install, cocoapods still uses the **git** username when retrieving the `Check` pod.

```
Installing Check (0.2.1)

[!] Error installing Check
[!] /usr/bin/git clone git@bitbucket.org:yyy/check-ios.git /var/folders/xt/95yx185s0ql4c2gg3p7nm3100000gn/T/d20220224-7816-tucdut --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 0.2.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/xt/95yx185s0ql4c2gg3p7nm3100000gn/T/d20220224-7816-tucdut'...
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How to make cocopods to use my username? Also, what's the best way to handle two different BitBucket repos in different accounts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository/43892558#43892558https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository ?

Comment: @Larme thanks for the answer. However, I work in a company and I can't commit a podfile that makes reference to my local key.

Comment: Your two Bitbucket account, one is for yourself, and one for your company? They are different? Then, set the Host in the config file to bitbucket.org, and the other one customize it for yourself.

Comment: Actually both are from my company, but different departments. Both are hosted on BitBucket.