# Is it possible to fetch a private repository with cocoapods or carthage?

Tags: github, cocoapods, carthage

I'm trying to get an SDK from a private repository on Github. It's a company repository but I have an access to it. It works fine when I add a pack directly with a repository link. but when I try to fetch it with cocoapods or Carthage, it says repository not found. I guess it's because it's in a private mode. Is there any hope?

Comment: Yes you can. You can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885763/cocoapods-with-private-git-repository/43892558#43892558 if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For CocoaPods, follow these instructions: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html